# Logisim, what gives with the red signals?

Tags: digital-logic

I'm a beginner with Logisim.

I am stuck on the following [circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgovi.png) and have been unable to find help on web.

What causes the red signals and how can I try and correct the situation?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Assumed Blue '1' and red lines are '0'. This circuit works like it should. For each XOR4 it has more then one high input, so the output is low.
2 input XOR:
A XOR B => A AND NOT(B) OR NOT(A) AND B.

truth table for a XOR4: http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/372062L-01/multisim/xor4/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Stuck at which point? Where is your actual question?

Comment: @dim He's spec'd an 8-wide pin on the left, but used the default "tristate" as "YES". This isn't what is desired, I'm sure. Should have chosen "NO" before putting the part into the schematic. A fix, without deleting and re-adding, is to edit it, set tristate=NO, then "touch" it during simulation. It will "fix itself" and stop emitting "don't know" values to the xor4 circuit. The red lines (error) will go away. (probably.)

Comment: @jonk Wow. Maybe it's because I don't use Logisim, but I'm amazed you could guess what his problem was, given his poor description. You, sir, have a hell of a crystal ball. However, unless the question is edited, I won't retract my close vote, because I still think it shouldn't be allowed to give such a poor description of a problem.

Comment: @dim That's fine. He said he's new to using the tool. And besides, the _red_ lines are pretty much a newbie error. It's almost _always_ because of the silly LogiSim default for pins (tristate.) It gets every newbie in trouble pretty much every time. So it was pretty obvious to me what he was asking. He's just not able to express the problem because he has no idea what is going on. That's actually expected, in my book. I don't think he _could_ clarify his question. Just lacks the knowledge to do so.

Comment: @jonk I admit I may lack some indulgence sometimes (still, there isn't even a question mark in what is supposed to be a question...) Anyway, rewarding the crystal ball, +1 for you.

Comment: I have edited the question a bit as I find it has great value given the common occurrence of the error amongst new users.  Have pity and bring it back to a neutral vote so it does not disappear. Also @jonk deserves a gold star for reading between the lines of the question as originally posted.

Comment: I agree that it is a common problem with LogiSim and that this answer might help others, too. I don't think you could have done much better asking, given what you knew then. Anyway, thanks for the gold star! :) (But it will take some serious votes to re-open. I don't see that happen much.)

Answer (score 2):

You have set up your 8-wide pin to support tri-state. You do NOT want to do that, I suspect. So select that pin and edit it. Tell it that "tristate" is NO. Once you've done that, it will STILL be wrong, though. Because the little 'X' values will still be there. So now you need to select the little "hand" icon and go touch the 8-wide pin and change those 'X' values to '0'.

Then things will work. That's because you won't be sending in "don't know" values into your xor4 circuits.

ALWAYS watch yourself using Logisim. A number of devices support tristating, but especially the pins are where you get into trouble.

Also, if you haven't done so already, ALSO always check the number of inputs on your logic gates. LogiSim likes to default to 5! Normally, you want 2. And it forces you to change that. It's a pain, since you almost never want 5 and far more often want 2. Why they chose that default?? No idea. But be aware of it and the fact that you can change it.

Comment: were you able to figure out what the OP was asking here?

Comment: @MarkYisri Yes, I'm pretty sure I figured it out correctly.